# Differential equations exercise existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Hi guys I have a question, consider the system: $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=f(\vec{x})$, with $f(t)$ locally lipschitziana:

-Let $\vec{x} = \vec{x}(t)$ an solution,
such that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty  }\vec{x}(t) = \vec{x_0}$, prove that $f(\vec{x_0}) = 0 $

Steps:

I think that $| f(x_0) -f(x(t))| \leq K|x_0 - x(t)|$ because f is locally lipschitziana then making you tend to infinity $|f(x_0) - f(x)| \leq 0 $ but i don't know how to conclude that this $f(x)$ is exactly $0$, it would be correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method does not work, and in fact this has nothing to do with "locally Lipschitz". The following result is known:

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $f =(f_1,\dots,f_n) \in C(D,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n):[t_0, \infty) \to D$ a solution of $x'(t)=f(x(t))$ such that
$$
x_0=(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n):=\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t)
$$
exists in $D$ (that is $x_0 \in D$). Then $f(x_0)=0$.

Proof:

Assume $f(x_0)=(f_1(x_0),\dots,f_n(x_0)) \not=0$. Then there exists some $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $\delta:= f_k(x_0) \not= 0$. W.l.o.g. let $\delta > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous we have $f_k(x(t)) \to \delta$ $(t \to \infty)$, so we find some $t_1 \ge t_0$ such that
$$
x_k'(t)=f_k(x(t)) \ge \frac{\delta}{2} \quad (t \ge t_1).
$$
For $t \ge t_1$ we obtain
$$
x_k(t)= x_k(t_1) + \int_{t_1}^t x_k'(s) ds \ge x_k(t_1) + (t-t_1)\frac{\delta}{2}. 
$$
Hence $x_k(t) \to \infty$ ($t \to \infty$) in contradiction to $x_k(t) \to \xi_k$ ($t \to \infty$).

Comment: :0 Thank you very much